# Dart convert a string into a condition statement

Tags: dart

I have some string conditions on my database, such as `"=="`, `"!="`, `">"`, `">="`... I want to use those conditions on my client side.

```
if (a myCondition b) print('ok')
```

How do I convert a string into an actual condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to parse your string and perform the appropriate comparison manually.  One way:

```dart
bool applyCondition(String comparison, dynamic a, dynamic b) {
  switch (comparison) {
    case '==':
      return a == b;
    case '!=':
      return a != b;
    case '>':
      return a > b;
    case '>=':
      return a >= b;
    // Other cases...
  }
}

if (applyCondition(myCondition, a, b)) {
  print('ok');
}
```

A slightly more compact (but likely less efficient) version with a `Map` instead of `switch`:

```dart
final comparatorTable = <String, bool Function(dynamic, dynamic)>{
  '==': (a, b) => a == b,
  '!=': (a, b) => a != b,
  '>': (a, b) => a > b,
  '>=': (a, b) => a >= b,
  // Other cases...
};

if (comparatorTable[myCondition]!(a, b)) {
  print('ok');
}
```